# How to remove all attributes in HTML tags

Tags: c#, uwp, html-agility-pack

I would like to remove all attributes from HTML tags, for example

```
<div class="" style="" >
```

I have attempted this using HTMLAgilityPack however it seems that SelectNodes will not work

```
foreach(var eachNode in HtmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*"))
{
   eachNode.Attributes.RemoveAll();
}
```

How would I make this work in C# for UWP?

Comment: How did you know it doesn't work?

Comment: SelectNodes is not available in UWP applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative to `SelectNodes("//*")`, you can use `Descendants()` which should return the same result :

```
foreach(var eachNode in HtmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants().Where(x => x.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Element))
{
    eachNode.Attributes.RemoveAll();
}
```

Comment: used same code to remove all attributes and got stack overflow exception. solved by filtering out descendants by `.Where(x => x.NodeType == HtmlNodeType.Element && x.Attributes.Any())`.

Comment: I would have expected there to be a _Descendants<T>_ overload.